# Bootstrap Button Group to dynamically Change Text, HREF and Icon - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a Bootstrap Button group that used a split button dropdown.  What I want to do is when you select an option from the dropdown, the text, href and icon will change on the button.  I can get the text to change just fine, but I'm getting stuck with changing the HREF attribute and the icon.

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
     <a href="http://google.com" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="standard">Search</span><span class="mobile"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span></a>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#" data-value="http://google.com" data-icon="fa fa-search">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-value="http://yahoo.com" data-icon="fa fa-music">Song Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" data-value="http://bing.com" data-icon="fa fa-search-plus">Advanced Search</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
     $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('a.btn').html($(this).text());
     $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('a.btn').attr('href') = $(this).data('value');
     $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('a.btn i').removeClass();
     $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('a.btn i').addClass($(this).data('icon'));
});
```

I'm want to use the data-values, because in the long run, this dropdown will be dynamic, the list will depend on which page it appears on.

Comment: Have you read my answer below? Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

ok... apparently everything is correct EXCEPT the href portion.

instead of

```
$(this).parents(".btn-group").find('a.btn').attr('href') = $(this).data('value');
```

use

```
$(this).parents(".btn-group").find('a.btn').attr('href', $(this).data('value'));
```

I have a couple console.logs displaying the results of the change, and it's all working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**HREF**

Your href doesn't change because

```
.attr('href') = $(this).data('value');
```

Is not the way to change an attribute. It should be:

```
.attr('href', $(this).data('value'));
```

**ICON**

The icon change doesn't work because

```
$(this).parents(".btn-group").find('a.btn').html($(this).text());
```

Removes the entire content from the a.btn, which includes the `<span>` which contains the `<i>` that contains the icon. Basically, this line also removes the `<span class="mobile"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>`, so there is nothing left to `removeClass` or `appendClass` to :-D!

Here is your working code: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16689/

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").on("click",function(){
    var icon = $(this).attr('data-icon');
    var html = $(this).html();
    $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('a.btn').html('<i class="'+icon+'"></i>'+html);
    $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('a.btn').attr('href', $(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

Comment: You're putting the `<i>` back in, which is also an option... But you're still removing the two `<span>`s upon the first change though. See my solution, it's a little cleaner since it doesn't overwrite the entire html contents of the `a.btn`, but just of the `span.standard`

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
document.getElementById('elementid').className = 'classname'
```

or a string replace:

```
document.getElementById('elementid').className
= document.getElementById('elementid').className.replace(your replace code)
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem... The problem is that the whole `<span><ì></i></span>` that contains the fontAwesome icon is no longer there after the contents of the `<a class="btn">` get replaced by the new text with the `html()` command ;-)